# Spring 3.2.0 no uri found

Tags: java, javascript

Following is:

**appServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <!-- <annotation-driven /> -->
    <!--  <context:annotation-config /> -->

      <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.interlace"/>


</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >




<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>




</web-app>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController  {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("/HelloWorld.jsp");
    }

}
```

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWorld/welcome/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
I am using spring 3.2.0 if have added all required jar files.I am using without maven.Please try to help me

Comment: What is the url being fired exactly?

Comment: I guess in the URL pattern part you need to define /* or /HelloWorld/*

Answer (score 0):

**From spring references documentation:**

The DispatcherServlet is an actual Servlet (it inherits from the HttpServlet base class), and
as such is declared in the web.xml of your web application. You need to map requests that you want the DispatcherServlet to handle, by using a URL mapping in the same web.xml file. This is standard Java EE Servlet configuration; the following example shows such a DispatcherServlet declaration and mapping:

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/example/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the preceding example, all requests starting with /example will be handled by the
DispatcherServlet instance named example.

Comment: @user3543785 Can you show us your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

Remove HelloWorld from your URI and try accessing by /welcome/hello